# Object does not support property or method attachEvent

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, enquire.js

i use library enquire.js, good library, but have some problem, in ie8. 
console have message "Object does not support property or method addListener" in file enquire.js, ok, use google and found solution:

```
if("addEventListener" in this.mql) {
        this.mql.addListener(this.listener);
    } else {
        this.mql.attachEvent('onclick', function(){
            console.log('ssss');
            this.listener;
    });
}
```

ok, now, i have message "Object does not support property or method attachEvent".
Any ideas?

Comment: You are not operating on a DOM Element. Maybe your resultset is empty and you try to invoke the method on `undefined`. Show more of your code to be sure -  Especially the part where your work with `this.mql`.

Comment: i thin i know, what problem, i found this forum https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/issues/52 - but, still doesn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/wlion/RespondMore/blob/master/respondmore.min.js - i use a another respond.js - and all wonderful.